# Parquet to_pandas memory leak

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

When reading a parquet file from disk and converting to a pandas data frame the memory allocated doesn't appear to be freed when the object goes out of scope. Any ideas why that is? The snippet below shows this issue:

```
import resource
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


# write df to parquet
def write_parquet(path):
    df = pd.DataFrame({str(i): np.random.randn(10000000) for i in range(10)})
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    pq.write_table(table, path)
    df = None


def read_parquet(path):
    pq.read_table(path, nthreads=1).to_pandas()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_parquet("test.parquet")
    for i in range(5):  # read in a loop
        read_parquet("test.parquet")
        print((f"Iteration {i}|MaximumResidentSetSize: "
               f"{resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1000}"))


$ python replicate.py
Iteration 0|MaximumResidentSetSize: 1653.36
Iteration 1|MaximumResidentSetSize: 2434.932
Iteration 2|MaximumResidentSetSize: 3216.204
Iteration 3|MaximumResidentSetSize: 3997.276
Iteration 4|MaximumResidentSetSize: 4778.736
```

This happens on Linux, pyarrow is version 0.3.0 and was installed using conda (conda-forge build).

Comment: Which version of pyarrow do you use? Is this in Linux or OSX? Self-built or from conda-forge or pypi?

Comment: We found the issue https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/685 and will probably do a new release soon.